# How to call ProcessPayment function in Google Pay react button?

Tags: reactjs, google-pay

I am integrating google pay in react application. According to documentation, when token is generated it will be pass to gateway for process payment. I am using @google-pay/button-react. How can I pass token to gateway. I didn't find anything in documentation. Is this library send token to gateway by itself?

From google tutorial to send token to gateway

```
 processPayment(paymentDetail) {
  const paymentToken = paymentDetail.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
  let paymentData = {
    orderId : '12331231232311',
    amount : '50.00'
  }
  axios.post("https://esqa.moneris.com/googlepay/googlepay-api.js", {
    body: JSON.stringify({
      paymentToken,
      paymentData
    })
  }).then(response => {
    if ( response && response.receipt && response.receipt.ResponseCode &&
    !isNaN(response.receipt.ResponseCode) )
    {
    if ( parseInt(response.receipt.ResponseCode) < 50 )
    {
    alert("Looks like the transaction is approved.");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Looks like the transaction is declined.");
    }
    }
    else
    {
    throw ("Error processing receipt.");
    }
  })
  
}

<GooglePayButton
                environment="TEST"
                paymentRequest={{
                    apiVersion: 2,
                    apiVersionMinor: 0,
                    allowedPaymentMethods: [
                    {
                        type: 'CARD',
                        parameters: {
                        allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY'],
                        allowedCardNetworks: ['MASTERCARD', 'VISA', 'DISCOVER', 'AMEX','DISCOVER','JCB','INTERAC'],
                        },
                        tokenizationSpecification: {
                        type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                        parameters: {
                            gateway: "moneris",
                            gatewayMerchantId: "monca05217"
                        },
                        },
                    },
                    ],
                    merchantInfo: {
                    merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
                    merchantName: 'Demo Merchant',
                    },
                    transactionInfo: {
                    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                    totalPriceLabel: 'Total',
                    totalPrice: '50.00',
                    currencyCode: 'USD',
                    countryCode: 'CA',
                    },
                    callbackIntents: ['PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION'],
                    emailRequired: true,
                }}
                onLoadPaymentData={paymentRequest => {
                    console.log('load payment data', paymentRequest);
                    this.processPayment(paymentRequest)

                }} 
                onPaymentAuthorized={(paymentData) => ({ 
                    transactionState: 'SUCCESS'                                       
                  })} 
                onReadyToPayChange={result => {
                  console.log('ready to pay change', result);
                  this.setState({isReadyToPay : result.isReadyToPay});
                }}                                     
                onCancel={() => alert('Cancelled')}
                existingPaymentMethodRequired = {true}                                  
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `processPayment` method from `onLoadPaymentData`.

Your `processPayment` is responsible for calling your backend and passing the payment token to your payment gateway.

Example:

```js
onLoadPaymentData={paymentRequest => {
  processPayment();
}}
```

```js
async function processPayment(paymentData) {
  const paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
  const response = await fetch("/backend/api", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      paymentToken,
      orderDetails: {/* details about your order */}
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://esqa.moneris.com/googlepay/googlepay-api.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." See code again I modified it

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call your PSP from the frontend. You shouldn't be. The flow should look something like **Browser** > **Your backend server** > **Your PSP**.

Comment: I used Nodejs and getting response as a function. "MonerisGooglePay() {
 this.error = false;
 this.session = null;
 this.channel = null;
 this.container = null;
 this.validateCallback = null;
 this.receiptCallback = null;
 this.host = "esqa.moneris.com";
 this.debug = false;
 this._credentials = null;
};
-------------------"

Comment: I think the problem is that you are actually requesting their JS library from Nodejs. I'm not familiar with Moneris, but you would need to find a way to make API calls using Nodejs. It doesn't look like they've got a Nodejs library: https://community.moneris.com/product-forums/f/5/t/36

Comment: Can you please see this link https://developer.moneris.com/en/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Google%20Pay/On%20The%20Web and let me know how can i implement processPayment function?

Comment: Sorry, this is beyond my area of expertise. I suggest reaching out to Moneris for advice.